# INSERT работает, а SELECT нет

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

```
<?php
$username='andriy';
$login=$_POST["login"];
$password=$_POST["pass"];
echo "$username $login $password<br>";

$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysite;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$result=$connection->exec("SELECT * FROM users");
echo "$result";
echo "<br>";
if($result==true)
    echo"TRUE";
else if ($result==false)
    echo "FALSE";
?>
```

Пробовал через mysql тоже самое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из документации

> PDO::exec() запускает SQL запрос на выполнение и возвращает количество строк, задействованых в ходе его выполнения.
>
> PDO::exec() **не возвращает результат выборки оператором SELECT**. Если вам нужно выбрать данные этим оператором единожды в ходе выполнения программы, **пользуйтесь методом PDO::query()**. Если требуется запускать один и тот же запрос на выборку множество раз, лучше создать подготовленный запрос PDOStatement методом PDO::prepare(), а затем запускать его методом PDOStatement::execute() столько раз, сколько потребуется.